# Create an array of arrays in jquery/javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

Can someone tell me how to create an array $custom_interval of key value pairs of days and hours:

```
custom_interval[[Mon][0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]]
custom_interval[[Tue][0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]]
```

So that in PHP, I should be able to say

```
$hours = $custom_interval[$day];
```

The code that I have written gives me

```
[object Object]
```

This is the code:

```
//create a 2 dimentional array of days and time intervals and assign it to hidden input form element.
        for(var i=0; i<uniquedayArray.length; i++) {
                innerArray.push(uniquedayArray[i]);
                for(j=0;j<timeArray.length; j++){
                  outerArray[innerArray] = timeArray[j];
                }
        }
        alert(outerArray);
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: In JavaScript arrays are object. you can try        `console.log(outerArray);` instead of `alert()`

Comment: This needs basic debugging first. Make use of `console.log` and you should be able to find out more.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I printed out in console log as you said,

Comment: I have selected Wed and thu as 2 days and my selected days are 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 . But I am only getting the last value.Object { wed="6" , wed,thu="6"} . Where as I was expecting Object{ wed = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ,thu =0 1 2 3 4 5 6} .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [Javascript objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)?

You could do something like:

```
var data = {
"monday" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
"tuesday" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
}
```

The you'd access information by saying `data.monday[4]`. The link introduces a method for dynamically creating these kinds of objects.

Comment: My outerArray is a javascript object : var outerArray ={};
var innerArray =[];